# How to set image height and width dynamically for vanilla-lazyload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading

Try to implement vanilla-lazyload on-page in where having multiple images with  and  tag. As per their demos, height and width are required to work the lazy load properly. But I don't how to set it before initializing the lazy load. Is there any way to set the height/width of each image by detecting aspect ratio before init lazy load? I can't set it through CSS because I don't know what image suppose to comes as those are dynamically served.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vanilla-lazyload

Demo: https://github.com/verlok/lazyload/blob/HEAD/demos/image_basic.html